# Синтаксическая ошибка в php: ParseError: "syntax error, unexpected ';'"

Tags: php

Пожалуйста подскажите, что означает ошибка:

```
 ParseError: "syntax error, unexpected ';'" (EXCEPTION) in "/Passport/src/infomcpe/Passport" at line 174
```

Строки:

```
173: if($this->getFristLogin($sender->getName() != null){
174: $sender->sendMessage("Последний вход: {$this->getFristLogin($sender->getName())}");
175: }
```

Comment: Зря исправили, действительно отвратительная ошибка автора

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пропущена закрывающая круглая скобка. Я ее добавил и обозначил ^.

```
if($this->getFristLogin($sender->getName() != null)){
                                                   ^
```

Comment: Cпасибо) , есть какие-то скрипты которые тоже так тычут?

Comment: Скрипты не нужны. Вы со временем сами научитесь находить такие ошибки. Просто внимательно читайте, что вам пишет интерпретатор. Думаю, что различные IDE могут помогать находить такие ошибки. Попробуйте поставить какую-нибудь.

Comment: *****Слепой****

Comment: Ее нет и поэтому ошибка. Добавьте ее.